# Proving orthogonal properties in $R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Proposition 4. Suppose that $X\prec\Bbb R^n$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$. Then
>
> (1) $X^\bot\prec\Bbb R^n,$
>
> (2) $X\cap X^\bot=\{0\},$
>
> (3) $(X^\bot)^\bot=X$.

I'm trying to prove these 3 propositions,

my attempt:

1. since $X$ is in $R^n$, $X$ orthogonal must be in $R^n$ as well? I am not sure.
2. $X$ intersection with $X$ orthogonal must be $0$ because there $X$ and $X$ orthogonal must be orthogonal to one another, therefore $x$ times $x$ orthogonal is $O$. Let $v$ is in $X$ intersection $X$ orthogonal => $v$ orthogonal $v$ => $v\cdot v = 0$ => $v=0$
3. I have no idea how to start this.. every questions similar to this on internet is somehow related with hilbert spaces or something but i've never heard of that

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to show that $X^{\bot}$ is a subspace.
   Clearly $0\in X^{\bot}$.
   Let $x\in X$ and $y,w \in X^{\bot}$, then $(y+w)\cdot x=y\cdot x+ w\cdot x=0$.
   Therefore $y+z\in X^{\bot}$. Finally, if $y\in X^{\bot}$ then clearly for any scalar $\alpha$, $\alpha y \in X^{\bot}$.
2. Assume $x\in X\cap X^{\bot}$. Then $x\cdot x=0$ and therefore $x=0$.
3. Use similar methods to show two sided inclusion. If you stuck you can ask.